# Powershell evaluating against each member of collection rather than collection

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-5.0

I have the following code:

```
$a = gci .\Areas -Recurse
($a[0].EnumerateFileSystemInfos()).Count
```

This is its output

```
PS C:\> ($a[0].EnumerateFileSystemInfos()).Count
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Why? When I run `gm -InputObject $a[0]`, I clearly see that a collection is returned.

```
EnumerateFileSystemInfos  Method         System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[System.IO.FileSystemInfo] EnumerateF...
```

Why is it evaluating `.Count` against each member of the collection rather than the collection itself? Also worth noting is that

```
($a[0].EnumerateFileSystemInfos()).Count()
```

returns an error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method named 'Count'.
At line:1 char:1
+ ($a[0].EnumerateFileSystemInfos()).Count()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Which is what I would expect if I were calling it against $a[0][0] but I'm not. What's going on and how can I retrieve the number of items in the collection?

Comment: 1. `a[0]` is not a collection, it's a single element, the output you cite as a proof is unrelated. 2. Why do use EnumerateFileSystemInfos if you already recurse into every directory?

Comment: As for the second half there is no `Count()` method so that has no meaning here

Comment: @wOxxOm How is the proof output unrelated?  I am recursively searching for directories with no files.

Comment: @Matt `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` has a `Count()` method so, because that's how `gm` identifies the return value of this command, I would expect that method to be present.

Comment: Because it's not a proof at all, the output is unrelated. You didn't specify `-Directory` so you already enumerate everything.

Comment: There is no `Count` property either, however, so exactly where PowerShell is getting that from (custom converter?) is mildly interesting. The problem we're seeing has to do with the fact that enumerables are automatically unrolled, but as to what `Count` is invoked or why it does things, I don't know.

Comment: @sirdak: `IEnumerable` only has a `Count()` method as an extension method. PowerShell does not support extension methods, so you can be sure that's not getting invoked. As an aside: `@($a[0].EnumerateFileSystemInfos()).Length` (with explicit coercion to an array) does what you expect, but I'm pretty sure `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` isn't needed in the first place.

Comment: It seems like a perfect example of an X/Y problem implemented in a wrong way. What is the actual goal?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ah, so because the extension method isn't present, powershell is coercing the IEnumerable into unrolling itself and then calling it against each member for some reason?

Comment: If you piped to `Measure-Object` you could get the count without unrolling.

Comment: @sirdank: that's what it's supposed to do, but `DirectoryInfo` has no `Count` member, so I'm slightly puzzled as to where that's coming from.

Comment: @wOxxOm I need to get a list of all empty directories so I was calling `gci -Recurse` and attempting to filter for no children in creative ways because `? { $_.Count -eq 0 }` wasn't working.. However, this question is about why this code is misbehaving. Also, please forgive me but I still don't see why my proof is no good except that it's possibly contaminated by files which, you are right, would of course have no children.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Array compatibility (internal). The property is sort of hardcoded into Powershell (correct me anyone if I'm wrong) and it returns 0 for null and empry stuff, 1 for ANY non-array item or an array with 1 element (unrolling it in many cases!), and actual length for arrays.

Comment: @Vesper: that checks out. `(2).Count` is `1`, `(2).GetType()` is `Int32`. `Int32`, of course, does not have `Count`. `Get-Member` doesn't mention this "super-`NoteProperty`" either.

Comment: FWIW, this behavior (having `.Count` on everything, even a single object that has no `Count`) was [added as a feature in PowerShell 3.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/) (which also happened to introduce the method-mapping-on-unrolled-enumerable we're seeing here). Prior to this, `Count` was only a synthesized property on collections. It makes some scenarios more obvious, but others just more confusing. More damningly, the documentation included with PowerShell itself doesn't seem to be covering it anywhere.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `(gm -InputObject 2 -Force).psobject.properties` so its part of the base object?

Comment: `$null.Count` outputs 0 with no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EnumerateFileSystemInfos()` returns an `IEnumerable`, more precisely, a `System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator'1`, thus each query to it returns a single object. And when you're piping the output to `Out-Default`, that cmdlet checks if the `IEnumerable` has more data, if yes, queries it again. That's why you get a sequence of 1's, because each object behind an enumerable is a single object and not an array.

You should instead use `GetFileSystemInfos()` to get your proper count, it returns an array.

Comment: In what way am I querying the IEnumerable? I would think wrapping it in parentheses before calling `Count` should mean it's requesting the property from the object, not its members.

Comment: You can't get access to all of the members of an `IEnumerable` at once, like with an array, therefore wrapping it into parentheses won't do.

Comment: That makes sense. Powershell is automatically unrolling it because it has no way of talking to the object directly like the C# extension methods. I confirmed that `GetFileSystemInfos()` works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

To get the number of items in the the collection`$a`:

```
$a.Count
```

I don't understand the need for added complexity, and a `.NET`/`C#` approach. Is there anything this provides that you require?

Comment: He wants a stuff behind `$a[0]` which is normally a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` (first dir in file listing, if any). However, not checking for methods might hurt him in the long run.

Comment: If `$a` is a dynamic collection with 0 or 1 item `.Count` does **NOT** work, it will return nothing. Be careful as any other case >=2 works, which may lead to a wrong assumption. Use `@($a).Count` instead.